# Translate genes in a FASTA file using seqinr and keep the annotation

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a flat `.txt` file that contains 5 genes in the [FASTA format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format). I have read this file as a FASTA file in R using `read.fasta()`. Then I have translated the DNA sequences of each gene into peptides using `getTrans()` which effectively translates each gene sequence.

However, once the sequences are translated, I lose all the titles or annotation for each gene and therefore I cannot easily tell which gene is which.

Is there some way to translate multiple genes in a fasta file while keeping the annotations?

Comment: You can names of the translated peptides using `names(peptides) <- names(fasta)`. The annotations from the fasta object map 1-to-1 to the peptide object.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it worked perfectly. Thank you!